# ASP.net CSS in IE not working (FF, Edge and chrome work)

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

Hi guys,

i have been debugging and reading for many hours but I can't seem to find the issue.

I'm not the most experienced coder so I turn to you guys.

I'm running an asp.net c# page created from a modified visual studio template.

In visual studio test every browser works like a charm but when now I published it to IIS, IE doesn't work anymore (other browsers do).

My master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Aanmelding.SiteMaster" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Portaal</title>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">     
          <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>  
    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="/Content/css" /> 
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />
    </head>
```

My page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Portaal" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Aanmelding._Default" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>Welkom. </h1>      
            </hgroup>            
        </div>
    </section>
```

My CSS:

```
html {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.button {
   border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;  
   padding: 9px 18px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
   -moz-border-radius: 40px;
   border-radius: 40px; 
   color: #e80c4d;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-family: Georgia, Serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;

   }
.button:hover {
   background: #e80c4e;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#e80c4e));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e80c4e);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e80c4e);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e80c4e);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e80c4e);
   color: white;
   }
.button:active {
   border-top-color: #ffffff;
   background: #ffffff;
   }

a.HyperLinkHover {
     color: #95FBCF;
     background-color:#ff0;
     background-color: #377CB1;   }  

a.HyperLinkHover:visited { color:Purple;}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: solid 10px #000;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

    a:link, a:visited,
    a:active, a:hover {
        color: #333;
    }

    a:hover {
        background-color: #c7d1d6;
    }

header, footer, hgroup,
nav, section {
    display: block;
}

mark {
    background-color: #a6dbed;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}

.clear-fix:after {
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

    h5 a:link, h5 a:visited, h5 a:active {
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}

#body {
    background-color: #fff;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

    .main-content {
        background: url("../Images/accent.png") no-repeat;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }


header .content-wrapper {
    padding-top: 20px; 
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: #e80c4d;
    font-size: .8em;
    height: 10px;
}


/* site title
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.site-title {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-family: Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    margin: 0;
}

.site-title a, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:active {
    background: none;
    color: #c8c8c8;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* login
----------------------------------------------------------*/
#login {
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

    #login a {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 3px;
        padding: 2px 3px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #login a.username {
        background: none;
        margin-left: 0px;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #login ul {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #login li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
    }


/* menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#menu {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

    ul#menu li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

        ul#menu li a {
            background: none;
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        ul#menu li a:hover {
            color: #e80c4d;
            text-decoration: none;
        }


/* page elements
----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* featured */
.featured {
    background-color: #e80c4d;
}

    .featured .content-wrapper {
        background-color: #e80c4d;        
        color: #3e5667;
        padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    }

        .featured hgroup.title h1, .featured hgroup.title h2 {
            color: #fff;
        }

        .featured p {
            font-size: 1.1em;
        }

/* page titles */
hgroup.title {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

hgroup.title h1, hgroup.title h2 {
    display: inline;
}

hgroup.title h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

/* features */
section.feature {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* ordered list */
ol.round {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

    ol.round li {
        margin: 25px 0;
        padding-left: 45px;
    }

        ol.round li.zero {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList0.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.one {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList1.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.two {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList2.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.three {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList3.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.four {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList4.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.five {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList5.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.six {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList6.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.seven {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList7.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.eight {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList8.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.nine {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList9.png") no-repeat;
        }

/* content */
article {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}

aside {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
}

    aside ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

        aside ul li {
            background: url("../Images/bullet.png") no-repeat 0 50%;
            padding: 2px 0 2px 20px;
        }

.label {
    font-weight: 700;

}



/* login page */
#loginForm {
    border-right: solid 2px #c8c8c8;
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
}

    #loginForm .validation-error {
        display: block;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

#socialLoginForm {
    margin-left: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}

    #socialLoginForm h2 {
        margin-bottom:  5px;
    }

fieldset.open-auth-providers {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

    fieldset.open-auth-providers button {
        margin-bottom: 12px;
    }

/* contact */
.contact h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.contact p {
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}

.contact iframe {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}

/* forms */
fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    fieldset legend {
        display: none;
    }

    fieldset ol {
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

        fieldset ol li {
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

    label {
        display: inline;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

        label.checkbox {
            display: block;
        }
        input:focus, textarea:focus {
            border: 1px solid #7ac0da;
        }

        input[type="checkbox"] {
            background: transparent;
            border: inherit;
            width: auto;
        }

    input[type="submit"],
    input[type="button"],
    button {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        border: 1px solid #787878;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 7px;
        margin-right: 8px;
        width: auto;
    }

    td input[type="submit"],
    td input[type="button"],
    td button {
        font-size: 1em;
        padding: 4px;
        margin-right: 4px;
    }

/* info and errors */
.message-info {
    border: 1px solid;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.message-error {
    clear: both;
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.message-success {
    color: #7ac0da;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.error {
    color: #e80c4d;
}

/* styles for validation helpers */
.field-validation-error {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}

input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
    border: 0 none;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}

/* tables
----------------------------------------------------------*/
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 0.75em;
    border: 0 none;
}

th {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    border: none 0px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

    th a {
        display: block;
        position: relative;

    }

    th a:link, th a:visited, th a:active, th a:hover {
        color: #333;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    th a:hover {
        color: #000;
    }

    th.asc a, th.desc a {
        margin-right: .75em;
    }

    th.asc a:after, th.desc a:after {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0em;
        top: 0;
        font-size: 0.75em;
    }

    th.asc a:after {
        content: '▲';
    }

    th.desc a:after {
        content: '▼';
    }

td {
    padding: 0.25em 2em 0.25em 0em;
    border: 0 none;
}

tr.pager td {
    padding: 0 0.25em 0 0;
}


/********************
*   Mobile Styles   *
********************/
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {

    /* header
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    header .float-left,
    header .float-right {
        float: none;
    }

    /* logo */
    header .site-title {
        margin: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* login */
    #login {
        font-size: .85em;
        margin: 0 0 12px;
        text-align: center;
    }

        #login ul {
            margin: 5px 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login li {
            display: inline;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login a {
            background: none;
            color: #999;
            font-weight: 600;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login a:hover {
            color: #333;
        }

    /* menu */
    nav {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    ul#menu {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

        ul#menu li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }


    /* main layout
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    .main-content,
    .featured + .main-content {
        background-position: 10px 0;
    }

    .content-wrapper {
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .featured .content-wrapper {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    /* page content */
    article, aside {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* ordered list */
    ol.round {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

        ol.round li {
            padding-left: 10px;
            margin: 25px 0;
        }

            ol.round li.zero,
            ol.round li.one,
            ol.round li.two,
            ol.round li.three,
            ol.round li.four,
            ol.round li.five,
            ol.round li.six,
            ol.round li.seven,
            ol.round li.eight,
            ol.round li.nine {
                background: none;
            }

     /* features */
     section.feature {
        float: none;
        padding: 10px;
        width: auto;
     }

        section.feature img {
            color: #999;
            content: attr(alt);
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-weight: 600;
        }

    /* forms */
    input {
        width: 90%;
    }



    /* login page */
    #loginForm {
        border-right: none;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }

        #loginForm .validation-error {
            display: block;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }

    #socialLoginForm {
        margin-left: 0;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }

    /* footer
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    footer .float-left,
    footer .float-right {
        float: none;
    }

    footer {
        text-align: center;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }

        footer p {
            margin: 0;
        }
}
/* END: Mobile Styles */
</pre>**
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: In what sense does IE not work?

Comment: what is not working ? what error do you get ?

Comment: which version of IE are you using?

Comment: Try changing your compatibility view settings.

Answer (score 0):

Many CSS3 features (like round border) are not supported in IE8 and under versions, better to use IE10 Or later one

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem.
When opening my site, the IE11 went to compatiblity mode IE7.
After toying around in the developer mode i tried switching the document mode to 11 and it immediately worked like a charm.
I simply added:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

to my master page, did a refresh and now everything works.

Thank you guys, for the responses.